# Create procedure in Oracle to populate table from SSRS parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, reporting-services, parameters

I have been running a report in Oracle for my customer where they provide a list of id numbers. I import the id numbers into a table and run a query which includes this table.  However, the customer would like the ability to run this report. I can create the report in SSRS and take a few id numbers, but not the entire list.  I would like to know if I can create a procedure that would check the table for data, delete if it exists, then import the data from the parameter in SSRS into the table which SSRS can then run the query which includes the newly populated table.  How would such a procedure look, and can that be called in SSRS with the parameter to include the id numbers that will be imported. I had thought of creating a temp table and populating it, but was advised that Oracle does not use temp tables, and I already have the table created within the database.

Comment: Oracle certainly has temp tables.

Comment: So do you have a procedure example to take parameter values and create a temp table to be used in a SSRS report?

Comment: They are different than SQLServer temp tables.  Read this https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables

Comment: I know they are different.  I'm just looking for an oracle procedure I can call in an SSRS report.  I have many reports on SSRS from the Oracle database with no issue.  I do appreciate the link and will check it out.  I do have existing tables, but if a temp table will take less resources than using an existing table, that is the way to go. The challenge I have is taking the parameter from the user when they run the report and populating said table.